# Using LINQ for Inner Join() method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, select, inner-join

I have two tables:

```
public class Game
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public int FirstTeamId { get; set; }
    public int GoalsFirstTeam { get; set; }
    public int GoalsSecondTeam { get; set; }
    public int SecondTeamId { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }
}
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Game> Games { get; set; }
}
```

Then, using:

```
       OperationDataContext dt = new OperationDataContext();
    public ActionResult Scores()
    {
        List<Games> model = dt.Games.ToList();
        var query = (from g in dt.Games
                     join t1 in dt.Teams on g.FirstTeamId equals t1.Id
                     join t2 in dt.Teams on g.SecondTeamId equals t2.Id
                     select new Games(){g.GameId, 
                                        t1.Name, 
                                        g.GoalsFirstTeam, 
                                        g.GoalsSecondTeam, 
                                        t2.Name
                                        }
                     ).ToList();
        model = query;
        return View(model);
```

What I am trying to ultimately achieve in View is this:

Game    FirstTeam   Goals  Goals SecondTeam

1       Roma        1      3     Manchester

2       Inter       0      0     Milan

Can somebody help me with this, because I'm getting error notifications ?

PS. When I try this:

```
OperationDataContext dt = new OperationDataContext();
    public ActionResult Scores()
    {
        var games = dt.Games.ToList();

        return View(games);
    }
```

The result is:

Game    FirstTeam   Goals  Goals SecondTeam

1       Roma        1      3     Roma

2       Inter       0      0     Inter

Comment: What are the error notifications exactly?

Comment: Class `Game` is not appropriate to accommodate the results produced by the linq query you perform.

Comment: Yes,I'm see this error notification: Unable to initialize "Tournament20.Models.Games" with a collection initializer because it does not implement the "System.Collections.IEnumerable". Simply, I don't understand how fix it .

Comment: Is this pure linq (linq to objects)?  Or entity framework?  If its entity framework, then you should just provide proper navigational properties.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 select new Games(){ g.GameId,
                     t1.Name, 
                     g.GoalsFirstTeam, 
                     g.GoalsSecondTeam, 
                     t2.Name
                    }
```

To an anonymous type:

```
select new { GameId = g.GameId,
             Team1 = t1.Name,
             Team2 = t2.Name,
             Team1Goals = g.GoalsFirstTeam, 
             Team2Goals = g.GoalsSecondTeam                 
             }
```

You can also define a new type - `GameResult` that consists the fields above.

Comment: `select new GamesResult{ GameId = g.GameId, FirstTeamId = t1.Name, FirstTeamId = t2.Name, Team1Goals = g.GoalsFirstTeam, Team2Goals = g.GoalsSecondTeam } `  - it's not works, because GamesResult - undefined. How and/or where define a new type - GameResult? Where I can read about this, because I'm not so good in it? ))

Answer (score 0):

As Erik suggested you can improve your model

```
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int FirstTeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Team FirstTeam { get; set; }

    public int GoalsFirstTeam { get; set; }
    public int GoalsSecondTeam { get; set; }

    public int SecondTeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Team SecondTeam { get; set; }

    //What does this mean??
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}


public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

Then you can query your data this way

```
OperationDataContext dt = new OperationDataContext();
public ActionResult Scores()
{
    var query = dt.Games.Select(g=> new 
                   {
                       Game = g.Id,
                       FirstTeam = g.FirstTeam.Name,
                       Goals_FT = g.GoalsFirstTeam,
                       Goals_ST = g.GoalsSecondTeam,
                       SecondTeam = g.SecondTeam.Name
                   }
    return View(query.ToList());
}
```

Hope it is clear and helpful,
Alessandro

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this way. `public Team Team { get; set; }` - it is navigation property in class Game that references class Team.

Comment: OK, for each single navigation property you need an id. In this case you have NP for team 1 and 2 so you don't need the last Team NP